# Sampling from conditional distribution using copula

Tags: r, conditional-probability, simulation, joint-distribution, copula

I'm using Clayton copula model to generate bivariate observations. x= poisson and y=gamma with, of course, certain dependence among them.

I have generated observations (X,Y) ~ f(x,y) using copula package in r but now I need to generate observation Y|X=x ~ f(Y|X=x) ¿Is there any way/algorithm to generate samples from conditional distribution that involves the copula? For example, like this, found in Nelsen:

1. Generate two independent uniform (0,1) variates u and t;
2. Set v = cu(-1)(t), where cu(-1) denotes a quasi-inverse of cu .
3. The desired pair is (u,v).

I have the next code in r where I model the observations according to Nelsen,using the quasi-inverse of cu from cCopula function:

```
    t<-runif(1700)
    u_t<-cbind(t,runif(1700))
    V<-cCopula(u_t,claytonCopula(param=0.14,dim=2),inverse=TRUE)
    x<-qpois(u_t[,1],lambda=d.poisson$estimate[1])
    y<-qgamma(V[,2],shape=claim_size.gamma$estimate[1],rate=claim_size.gamma$estimate[2])
    plot(data_sinout$d,data_sinout$claim_size,main='Test dataset x and y',col='blue')
    points(x,y,col='red')
  legend('topright', c('Observed', 'Simulated'), col = c('blue', 'red'), pch=21)
```

The result is:

[image]

which is quite reasonable being one of my first tries.

Now I want to generate observations of Y when X=15, it means f(Y|X=15), then according to the data I expect to have low values of y, in the range of [0,50k].So, I have this code:

```
t_x<-15
t<-ppois(t_x,lambda=d.poisson$estimate[1])
u_t<-cbind(t,runif(1700))
V<-cCopula(u_t,claytonCopula(param=0.14,dim=2),inverse=TRUE)
x<-qpois(u_t[,1],lambda=d.poisson$estimate[1])
y<-qgamma(V[,2],shape=claim_size.gamma$estimate[1],rate=claim_size.gamma$estimate[2])
plot(data_sinout$d,data_sinout$claim_size,main='Test dataset x and y',col='blue')
points(x,y,col='red')
legend('topright', c('Observed', 'Simulated'), col = c('blue', 'red'), pch=21)
```

but instead I have:

[image]

which is not what I was expecting. Any help would be really appreciate it.

Comment: Thank you Ben. Indeed, it was helpful but I can't install the spcopula package, instead I use the cCopula function from copula package that results in the same: conditional copula and its inverse but I have rare results. Can you have a look at my code, please?

Comment: You could try to install spcopula from gitHub: http://https://github.com/BenGraeler/spcopula 
However, your copula has a very small correlation (0.06), hence, the conditioning does not have "any" effect und what you get is a plain sample from the marginal distribution.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Ben,that was quite concise, clear and reasonable ¡¡  so, just to finish with this. If I had a data with an "adequate" correlation thus my copula, my code would correctly work and I would see the effect of the conditional, right?